# AVR Assembly - Operations with two 8-bit registers in 16-bit two complement negative values

Tags: assembly, avr

I have this code in which I try to multiply the given number by 4. I have two variants and that is that it is negative and positive, but it doesn't work for negative values, you don't know why?

```
.org 0
start:
    ldi r16, -120 
    ;(r21:r16) 

    ;WORK WITH  -
    cpi r16,0
    brge zaporny
    ldi r21, 0xFF 
    ;r16*4
    lsl r16
    ;kontrola overflow
    BRVC over
    dec r21
    over:
    lsl r21
    lsl r16
    BRVC over1
    dec r21
    over1:
    zaporny:
```

Comment: `dec r21` makes no sense. You need to shift the bit in that you shifted out from the low byte. As I said in your other question, use `ROL` for the high byte. Also ask a compiler.

Comment: Can I ask you to divorce it a bit, should I replace that decrementation with ROL?

Comment: It's just `lsl r16; rol r21; lsl r16; rol r21`.

Comment: `ldi r21, 0xFF` - are you trying to sign-extend an 8-bit number to 16-bit?  Before you left-shift it twice?